# How do I make my program run and interact with shell program?

Tags: java, ubuntu, io, terminal, processbuilder

There is a program I run in Ubuntu terminal, called ProgramABC, which reads a query until user presses CTRL+D, and then writes some data to the standard output. It works perfectly:

```
/path/ProgramABC >> file.txt [enter]
<here I write my query> [enter]
<and I press CTRL+D>
<data is written to file.txt and ProgramABC closes automatically>
```

I want to run it from Java. My code doesn't work - it creates the file.txt, but it's empty, so I guess something is wrong with passing my query to the process, and therefore to ProgramABC. What do I do wrong? Here is a part of my code:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash","-c","/path/program ABC >> file.txt");
    builder.directory(new File("/another/path/"));
    Process process = builder.start();


    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

    writer.write("<my query here>");
    writer.write((char)4); //it's CTRL+D, right?
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```